# DPI aware PDF viewer for Linux

Tags: linux, pdf

I have a full HD monitor that has a non-standard 103 DPI.

I like to view PDFs at their print size. But because I can't set the DPI in the PDF viewer, I have to display a document at 107%.

Evince would work, but only with a Nvidia driver that reported the correct DPI. And that is not happening:

[image]

Adobe Acrobat has this function to set a custom DPI. Is there any other Linux / Ubuntu PDF viewer that has this option? Also I prefer free / open-source applications.

Comment: One problem - not all monitors report their DPI correctly to the computer. So it may not always be possible.

Comment: @MichaelKohne I realize that. The only thing I'm asking for is an option in the viewer to set DPI.

Comment: what about `/usr/bin/xrandr --dpi` with evince?